# JS/HTML - how to allow user to edit text from mysql table? Display previous text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I working with PHP here and Basically I have user accounts that are within a larger mysql table (called accounts) and I have an "about me" text field for each user.

I need to be able to allow users to click a button and edit their existing about me blurb - as in I need the old text to be displayed and able to be edited or added to, then when they click the button again this new edited blurb is saved back to the mysql database.

Initially I tried this with a text input but this did not allow them to edit existing text, just replace the whole thing -

```
echo '<form class="blurbForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<div class="changeBlurb">Change Your Blurb</div>';
echo '<div class="blurbBtn" method="post"></div>';
echo '<input class = "blurbText" type="blurb" placeholder="Blurb" name="blurbText">';
echo '</form>';
```

So then I looked into rich text editors and have now installed Medium.js (https://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/):

```
<script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
```

So right now I have an invisible text editor where text can be entered:

[image]

I will format the editor but want to know how I can display/have users EDIT existing blurb text? Am I on the right path with Medium.js or is there a better way of having a user edit a paragraph from a mysql table?